# Numpy: using np.mean in 3 dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, mean, dimensions, netcdf

I have 140 arrays which have the dimensions 734 x 1468. I need the mean across the 140 arrays in the 734 x 1468 entries, I started by iterating through the data with nested for loops but it is way too slow. I have tried using the `np.mean` function

```
res = np.mean([megadatalist[i].variables['analysed_sst'][0] for i in range(0,140)], axis=2)
```

`res.shape` gives (140, 734)

I need a result of the dimensions 734, 1468

`megadatalist` consists of 140 netCDF files.

Comment: Try `axis=0` instead of `axis=2`.

Comment: oh my, that seems to be working, now I feel dumb :D

Comment: Don't feel dumb.  Getting mixed up over axes is a normal part of life with NumPy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing a list of arrays which is casted to (140,734,1468). So either you use np.dstack as shown below, or you can change `axis=0`.

With `np.dstack`:

```
X = np.dstack([megadatalist[i].variables['analysed_sst'][0] 
        for i in range(0,140)])

res = np.mean(X, axis=2)
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. It works! Didnt knew of Dstack until now, thats incredibly smart, thank you so much!

Comment: "You are passing a list of arrays instead of a 3D array" <- It shouldn't matter: NumPy should treat the list as though it were an array of shape `(140, 734, 1468)`.  All that's necessary here is to change `axis=2` to `axis=0`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, it does matter in the sense that arrays are casted to (D,H,W) instead of (H,W,D). Anyway, both solutions are fine. I edited the answer to take both into account.